# How to refactor to get two values from the same function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, algorithm, datepicker, refactoring

Dev newbie here, trying to fix some features on a website.
I have this code initializing the "date to" input / datepicker on a search page, and it's a couple of date from -> date to  inputs that are supposed to range from far far away in the past, until now. So when a date from is picked, the date from has all the dates prior to the date to date disabled, and naturally all the dates greater than today disabled.

I have the "all the dates prior to the date to date" disabled function, and the "all dates greater than today" disabled function too, but working separatly. 
I tryed to refactor them in one function that does it all, but I have 0 clue, as I told before, I'm a newbie, so I ask big brothers. Thank you for your help. 
Here is the code :

```
 // Field working with the dateFrom used on the calendar view.
    var dateToFilterUnlimited = $("#dateToFilter.unlimitedDateFilter")
    .fdatepicker($.extend({}, datepickerCommonOptions, {
        onRender: 
        function(date) {
            return date.valueOf() > now.valueOf() ? "disabled" : "";
        }
    }))
    .fdatepicker($.extend({}, datepickerCommonOptions, {
        onRender: function (dateMin) {
            return dateMin.valueOf() <= dateFromFilterUnlimited.date.valueOf() ? "disabled" : "";
        }
    }))
    .on("changeDate", function() {
        dateToFilterUnlimited.hide();
    })
    .data("datepicker");
```

---

Thank you guys, here it is working :

```
// Field working with the dateFrom used on the calendar view.
var dateToFilterUnlimited = $("#dateToFilter.unlimitedDateFilter")
.fdatepicker($.extend({}, datepickerCommonOptions, {
    onRender:
    function(date) {
        if (date.valueOf() > now.valueOf()){
            return "disabled";
        }

        if (date.valueOf() <= dateFromFilterUnlimited.date.valueOf()){
            return "disabled";
        }

        return "";
    }
}))
.on("changeDate", function() {
    dateToFilterUnlimited.hide();
})
.data("datepicker");
```

Comment: How about returning a JSON object with two elements? For instance: `return {Date_Value: ...., Date_Min: .....}`.

Comment: @FDavidov isn't that just an object?

Comment: @freedomn-m, don't quite understand your question. Please rephrase.

Comment: @FDavidov `return { a:123, b:456 }` returns an *object* - it's not *JSON*

Comment: Doesn't look like you're *returning* two values - looks like you want to *check* two values.  You can combine the two checks with `&&` or use multiple `if`s (as answer already provided) - eg: `date.valueOf() > now.valueOf() && dateMin.valueOf() <= dateFromFilterUnlimited.date.valueOf() ? "disabled" : ""`  (also now in the answer following an edit)

Comment: @freedomn-m, ahh, of course, it is an object like any element within JavaScript. The point is that it contains the two data elements that the PO is asking to convey as the returned of the function.

Comment: @freedomn-m JSON means JavaScript Object Notation. So considering the context saying "returns an object - not a JSON", is the same as "returns an object - not an object". I mean simply saying object is completely fine, but saying that javascript object is not a JSON is wrong.

Comment: @user3707125 somewhat off topic as the user isn't even trying to "return" anything - but no, JSON is not an object, it's an object *notation* (as you state) - ie it's a string (you're welcome to argue that a 'string' in javascript is still an 'object'...)   So it would be `return '{"a":123}';` rather than `return {a:123}`.   If you want to return JSON then you would do `return JSON.stringify({a:123});`.   Even the method name is a clue "*string*ify".  But if it's not in a string (as it's not in this case) then it's not JSON.

Answer (score 1):

you might just use some `if` statements:

```
var dateToFilterUnlimited = $("#dateToFilter.unlimitedDateFilter")
.fdatepicker($.extend({}, datepickerCommonOptions, {
    onRender: 
    function(date) {
        if(date.valueOf() > now.valueOf())
          return "disabled";

        if(dateMin.valueOf() <= dateFromFilterUnlimited.date.valueOf())
           return "disabled";

        return "";
    }
}));
```

For sure you could also just do some logic operations:

```
return date.valueOf() > now.valueOf() ||
       dateMin.valueOf() <= dateFromFilterUnlimited.date.valueOf()
       ? "disabled"
       : "";
```

Comment: Thank you it worked *british aristocratic accent* :  magnificently !

Comment: @hid3f glad to help :)